# Can't attach database in SSMS

Tags: sql-server

For my homework assignment I'm told to download a zip folder holding a `.mdf` file for the database I'm going to be working on. So I extracted the file and saved it. I then went into SSMS went to attach the database and I got this error?

```
===================================

Attach database failed for Server 'DESKTOP-VDSUPUV\SQLEXPRESS'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

------------------------------
For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=15.0.18206.0+((SSMS_Rel).191029-2112)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Attach+database+Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.AttachDatabase(String name, StringCollection files)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.AttachDatabaseData.PrimaryFile.Attach()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.AttachDatabase.SendDataToServer()

===================================

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries, Boolean retry)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.AttachDatabaseWorker(String name, StringCollection files, String owner, AttachOptions attachOptions)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.AttachDatabase(String name, StringCollection files)

===================================

Unable to open the physical file "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Databases\PR_log.ldf". Operating system error 2: "2(The system cannot find the file specified.)".
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=13.00.5026&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=5120&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Server Name: DESKTOP-VDSUPUV\SQLEXPRESS
Error Number: 5120
Severity: 16
State: 101
Line Number: 1


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)
```

I downloaded only one .mdf file there is no log file. I was told however when I try to attach,if there isn't a log file then one is created automatically. In this pic that's what it looks like?[image]

Comment: The error tells you exactly what the problem is "Unable to open the physical file "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Databases\PR_log.ldf"". You're missing the log file.

Comment: Either the file is missing OR SQL Server doesn't have permission to access. SQL Server by default doesn't have access to many locations.

Comment: @DaleK I thought that SQL Server automatically creates a new log file if there isn't one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options to do this:

1. When you attach the mdf file, in the bottom pane, choose the LDF file and remove it and choose OK. The database will be attached. [Reference](https://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/how-to-attach-mdf-file-without-ldf-file/)

[image: Removing LDF file]

2. You can use TSQL to attach database.

```sql
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [PR] ON 
( FILENAME = N'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Databases\PR.mdf' )
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG 
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Try copy to SQL location installed at DATA Folder.

**Example**: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLExpress\MSSQL\DATA

Comment: Didn't work. I moved the file to  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLExpress\MSSQL\DATA and tried attaching it from there but same error?

Comment: Does you have 2 file *.mdf and *.ldf?

Comment: Yes I do, there wasn't one originally so a new one was created

Comment: Incorrectly, MDF and LDF is a pair file, we can' create them by manual. They was born when create database at the first time and if you move database,  you must copy them at the same time. Don't copy only MDF file.

Comment: I didn't create it manually, it's created automatically since there isn't one present. I've attatched an .mdf file before without a log and it worked before?

Comment: It still say: "Unable to open the physical file "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Databases\PR_log.ldf"" or "Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLExpress\MSSQL\DATA\PR_log.ldf""?

Comment: Maybe it relating to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926096/how-to-attach-a-database-without-an-ldf-file